# Kotlin generic post request

Tags: api, generics, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, retrofit2.6

Hio, i´m working on a generic interface for Retrofit API calls in Kotlin. I´m kinda new to Kotlin and i feel like i´m missing something important. i tried to search for a solution but didnt found one.

This is my interface

```
@JvmSuppressWildcards
interface GenericApiRequest {

@POST("/stuff")
suspend fun <TIn, TOut>getResponse(@Body request: TIn) : TOut
}
```

This the code where i use it

```
val response = client.getResponse<RequestDataClass, ResponseDataClass>(RequestDataClass("stuff"))
```

This is the Error I get:

```
Parameter type must not include a type variable or wildcard: TIn (parameter #1)
    for method GenericApiRequest.getResponse
```

I thought it would be solved by the @JvmSuppressWildcards but it didnt helped. Has someone a solution for this?

Comment: Can you please try using version retrofit_version = "2.6.2" ,  for me it's working fine without using @JvmSuppressWildcards

Comment: I have it on the newest version and it still dosnt work for me. The strange thing is that it should work, but dosnt,